# remove empty rows from lookup edit in devexpress

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, devexpress

I'm working on a winforms application and i have a look up edit field.
The data is loaded but i got many empty rows in the lookup edit.

Any help?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It look like you do not provide unique values in to lookup function. Moreover your select returns "empty" values. There was a similar discussion on DevExpress forum: http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/B207643